# Limitation on what can be borrowed

Tags: debt, liquidity

Is there a framework for determining the limit of what can be borrowed?

For example, lets say an institution with 1 trillion USD wanted to hold 5 trillion USD in government bonds, would there be a collection of other institutions willing and capable of lending the 4 trillion, is there a way to determine the maximum liquidity of an ecosystem?